# Получить атрибуты элементов из таблицы через JQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, table

Есть таблица, в которой повторяются эти строчки:

```
<div class="input-group input-number-group"> 
  <div class="input-group-button">
    <span class="input-number-decrement changeQuantity">-</span>
  </div> 
  <input class="input-number" type="number" data-id="49" value="0" min="0" max="1000"> 
  <div class="input-group-button"> 
    <span class="input-number-increment changeQuantity">+</span> 
  </div>
</div>
```

Нужно получить из таблицы из всех `.input-number` значения атрибутов `data-id` и `value` и записать их в ассоциативный массив по типу 
`arr[id][0]="49"`, `arr[value][0]="0"`…

Вот пример таблицы:

```
<table id="goodsBasket" class="table-responsive w-100 d-block d-md-table">
   <tbody>
      <tr>
         <th>Изображение</th>
         <th>Название</th>
         <th>Описание</th>
         <th>Производитель</th>
         <th>Магазин</th>
         <th>Количество</th>
         <th>Действие</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td><img src="images/goodsImages/05-16-18-10-12-59.jpg"></td>
         <td>dfd</td>
         <td>dfd</td>
         <td>dfd</td>
         <td>rtytry</td>
         <td>
            <div class="input-group input-number-group">
               <div class="input-group-button"> <span class="input-number-decrement changeQuantity">-</span> </div>
               <input class="input-number" type="number" data-id="49" value="0" min="0" max="1000"> 
               <div class="input-group-button"> <span class="input-number-increment changeQuantity">+</span> </div>
            </div>
         </td>
         <td><button data-id="49" type="button" class="btn btn-danger deleteFromSession">Удалить из корзины</button></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td><img src="images/goodsImages/05-16-18-10-02-30.jpg"></td>
         <td>sgfdgf</td>
         <td>sgfdgf</td>
         <td>sgfdgf</td>
         <td>rtytry</td>
         <td>
            <div class="input-group input-number-group">
               <div class="input-group-button"> <span class="input-number-decrement changeQuantity">-</span> </div>
               <input class="input-number" type="number" data-id="48" value="0" min="0" max="1000"> 
               <div class="input-group-button"> <span class="input-number-increment changeQuantity">+</span> </div>
            </div>
         </td>
         <td><button data-id="48" type="button" class="btn btn-danger deleteFromSession">Удалить из корзины</button></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td><img src="PATH"></td>
         <td>test</td>
         <td>test</td>
         <td>test</td>
         <td>rtytry</td>
         <td>
            <div class="input-group input-number-group">
               <div class="input-group-button"> <span class="input-number-decrement changeQuantity">-</span> </div>
               <input class="input-number" type="number" data-id="53" value="0" min="0" max="1000"> 
               <div class="input-group-button"> <span class="input-number-increment changeQuantity">+</span> </div>
            </div>
         </td>
         <td><button data-id="53" type="button" class="btn btn-danger deleteFromSession">Удалить из корзины</button></td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Приведите полный код таблицы в вопросе.

Comment: дак и в чем сложность то у вас собственно?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Используйте `$.map()` для обхода всех инпутов и `.get()` для получения результирующего массива.

```js
var result = $(".input-number").map(function(idx,v){ 
                     return { 
                          id: $(v).data('id'), 
                          value: $(v).val() 
                        } ;
                  }).get();
                  
console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="goodsBasket" class="table-responsive w-100 d-block d-md-table">
   <tbody>
      <tr>
         <th>Магазин</th>
         <th>Количество</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>rtytry</td>
         <td><input class="input-number" type="number" data-id="49" value="0" min="0" max="1000"></td>         
      </tr>
      <tr>         
         <td>rtytry</td>
         <td><input class="input-number" type="number" data-id="48" value="2" min="0" max="1000"></td>         
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>rtytry</td>
         <td><input class="input-number" type="number" data-id="53" value="3" min="0" max="1000"></td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

если я правильно понял вопрос, то небольшая корректировка к предыдущему ответу.

```js
var result = $(".input-number").map(function(idx,v){ 
                     return { 
                          [$(v).data('id')]: $(v).val() 
                        } ;
                  }).get();
                  
console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="goodsBasket" class="table-responsive w-100 d-block d-md-table">
   <tbody>
      <tr>
         <th>Изображение</th>
         <th>Название</th>
         <th>Описание</th>
         <th>Производитель</th>
         <th>Магазин</th>
         <th>Количество</th>
         <th>Действие</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td><img src="images/goodsImages/05-16-18-10-12-59.jpg"></td>
         <td>dfd</td>
         <td>dfd</td>
         <td>dfd</td>
         <td>rtytry</td>
         <td>
            <div class="input-group input-number-group">
               <div class="input-group-button"> <span class="input-number-decrement changeQuantity">-</span> </div>
               <input class="input-number" type="number" data-id="49" value="0" min="0" max="1000">
               <div class="input-group-button"> <span class="input-number-increment changeQuantity">+</span> </div>
            </div>
         </td>
         <td><button data-id="49" type="button" class="btn btn-danger deleteFromSession">Удалить из корзины</button></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td><img src="images/goodsImages/05-16-18-10-02-30.jpg"></td>
         <td>sgfdgf</td>
         <td>sgfdgf</td>
         <td>sgfdgf</td>
         <td>rtytry</td>
         <td>
            <div class="input-group input-number-group">
               <div class="input-group-button"> <span class="input-number-decrement changeQuantity">-</span> </div>
               <input class="input-number" type="number" data-id="48" value="0" min="0" max="1000">
               <div class="input-group-button"> <span class="input-number-increment changeQuantity">+</span> </div>
            </div>
         </td>
         <td><button data-id="48" type="button" class="btn btn-danger deleteFromSession">Удалить из корзины</button></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td><img src="PATH"></td>
         <td>test</td>
         <td>test</td>
         <td>test</td>
         <td>rtytry</td>
         <td>
            <div class="input-group input-number-group">
               <div class="input-group-button"> <span class="input-number-decrement changeQuantity">-</span> </div>
               <input class="input-number" type="number" data-id="53" value="0" min="0" max="1000">
               <div class="input-group-button"> <span class="input-number-increment changeQuantity">+</span> </div>
            </div>
         </td>
         <td><button data-id="53" type="button" class="btn btn-danger deleteFromSession">Удалить из корзины</button></td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```